# Child Application Menu not shown in a Chrome like application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a chrome like application. I do have two applications Say Parent and Child Application. Child application contains menus. 
When i am attaching an instance of child application to a tab of parent application. Menu in child application is not shown on mouse click.

Code snippet used for attaching process is

```
Process P = Process.GetProcessesByName("Child");
P.WaitForInputIdle();
IntPtr handle = P.MainWindowHandle;
SetParent(handle, this.tabPage1.Handle);
MoveWindow(handle, rec.X, rec.Y, rec.Width, rec.Height, true);
```

I cannot make any changes to Child application.

Comment: Does the same happen if you use a trivial application like Notepad?

Comment: There is no problem with notepad. Notepad's menus are working fine.